# In Ubuntu 22 how to replicate terminal colour scheme from Ubuntu 16

Tags: command-line, color-management, scheme

I liked the colour scheme of the terminal window in Ubuntu 16 and want to setup my newly installed Ubuntu 22 to the same ... but the colour schemes listed under preferences don't seem to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In the settings of the profile, you can customize each and every color individually. So yes, you can do it.